# Transferring Data from multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Objective - extracting data from multiple workbooks (5 in total); pasting the data into a new workbook.

Problem/Issue:
**1)** After running the below VBA code it's able to copy data from all the 5 workbooks but while pasting it's pasting data for only one of them.
**2)** Pop-up window for Clipboard is full. I've written a code to clear the clipboard but it doesn't seem to function as I still get the pop-up window.

VBA Code:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow

Dim MyPath As String

MyPath = "Directory path"

MyFile = Dir(MyPath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "filename.xlsb" Then
End If

       Workbooks.Open (MyPath & MyFile)
       Range("A3:CP10000").Copy
       ActiveWorkbook.Close

'calculating the empty row

 erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

a = ActiveWorkbook.Name
b = ActiveSheet.Name

Worksheets("Raw Data").Paste Range("A2")

Application.CutCopyMode = False ' for clearing clipboard

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

I tried two other commands below as well, but they seem to just return no data at all.

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow + 1, 1), Cells(erow + 1, 30)) `pasting the data`
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")`pasting the data`
```

---

**Update.**
Here is the current code:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow As Long
Dim MyPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

MyPath = "C:\Users\username\Downloads\PROJECTS\Project Name\Input file\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If InStr(MyFile, "post_level.xlsb") > 0 Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
        Range("A3:CP10000").Copy

        'calculating the empty row
         erow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Paste (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A" & erow + 2))

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90

End Sub
```

---

**Update2.**

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow As Long
Dim MyPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

MyPath = "C:\Users\username\Downloads\PROJECTS\ProjectNameFolder\SubFolder\MainFolder\Input file"
MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\username\Downloads\PROJECTS\ProjectNameFolder\SubFolder\MainFolder\Input file\*.*")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If InStr(MyFile, ".csv") > 0 Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
        Range("A3:CP10000").Copy

        'calculating the empty row
         erow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Paste (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A" & erow + 2))

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I see only one file designated - `filename.xlsb`. How are other files named?

Comment: Do you need to transfer all the 5 sheets/worksheets from the same workbook? Or do you need to transfer 1 sheet data from 5 workbooks/files? **sheet/worksheet is a different thing than workbook/file!**

Comment: I need to transfer data from 5 different woorkbooks into a new workbook. Every workbook contain data in one sheet only.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help... There are multiple errors in your code, and I am not sure if I fixed them the way you'd want.

It would be useful to mention just one main mistake. You **cannot** have these 2 lines together:

```
If MyFile = "filename.xlsb" Then
End If
```

**Between** these lines you must put every procedure that you want to do IF he `If` condition is met. In the original case, if there was a file named "filename.xlsb", nothing would have happened, as you immediately closed the code block...

Try something similar to the following code. It worked for me to import data from all the files in the directory `C:\Temp\` which have the extension of `.xlsb`

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow As Long
Dim MyPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

MyPath = "C:\Temp\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If InStr(MyFile, ".xlsb") > 0 Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
        Range("A3:CP10000").Copy

        'calculating the empty row
         erow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Paste (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A" & erow + 2))

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Were you able to find the problem because the code isn't extracting any data.

Comment: If you need it to work with .csv files, just try changing the extension. In my code it's the part `InStr(MyFile, ".xlsb")` - it should be changed to simply `InStr(MyFile, ".csv")` . I see in your current code that you inputted the full file name `"post_level.xlsb"` . Don't do it. This part says which files will be opened and data from them extracted. If you write just one file name, then just one file will be opened. And you said that you need 5 files. I suggest leaving `".csv"` if you have all of your .csv files in that folder and no other .csv files exist there.

Comment: Ppost_level.xlsb" is the file which will contain the above VBA Code and this will be run through Buttons created in another sheet. Now if I change the file extension to ".csv" then the VBA code will be gone. Just to add, my code (in the 1st post" is working perfectly fine but the only problem with that code is that it's copying data from all the 5 sheets but pasting data of only one sheet.

Comment: Put that VBA into your .xlsb file, but don't write it's name in that place where you want to write it. As I said, that place is for your .csv files.

Comment: You said you call that VBA code from another sheet using a button. Is that sheet containing that button in the same workbook (post_level.xlsb)? Then simply assign that button to this VBA and you are done.

Comment: I did not mean to rename your file to .csv . Just in the code you should CALL files with .csv extension. And you do that exactly in this place: `If InStr(MyFile, ".csv") > 0 Then` . Your file which contains your VBA code can remain .xlsb

Comment: Yes the button will be in the same workbook (post_level.xlsb) but in a different sheet. Currently I've not assigned the macro onto the button. Just  running the code through VBE. Also, I always follow the same that is Insert -> Module and put the VBA into that module.

Comment: Ok, everything is ready then. Just remove the name of your file from the code. Your code knows which file it is run from and it is not necessary. Copy-paste this line and you're done: `If InStr(MyFile, ".csv") > 0 Then` . Also, make sure that `MyPath` is the directory containing your 5 .csv files.

Comment: Now, getting error = Getting Run Time error '1004':

Sorry, we couldn't find "C:\Users\username\Downloads\PROJECTS\Main Folder\Sub Folder\Facebook\Input file"filename".csv.

Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Comment: Leave `MyFile = Dir(MyPath)` as is. You inserted a specific filename instead of just MyPath. This is why you get an error.

Comment: I know the that I'm not suppose to insert the filename in MyFile = Dir(MyPath) but I did so because when keep the code as MyFile = Dir(MyPath) and Hit Run or F5 nothing happens.

Comment: That's because your current `MyPath` does not have ` \ ` at the end. It must have this backslash symbol. I mean not `Input file"` but `Input file\"`

Comment: Sorry, got little busy with work. Yes it did. Thank you Buddy!